Numerical convolution of Gaussian and Lorentzian to get Voigt profile. Why not?
Voigt function is commonly used function is spectroscopy to describe the frequency distribution of the line absorption coefficient. Different processes that broaden spectral lines can be described individually either as Lorentzian (dispersion profile) or as Gaussian function (Doppler profile). To account for their combined effect, the Gaussian and Lorentzian are convolved in the $-\infty, +\infty$ range. The result of this convolution (described in virtually any book on spectroscopy) is the Voigt profile. However, as the Voigt profile is non-trivial to evaluate, in practice people use various approximations of this integral.
As both Gaussian and Lorentzian are defined analytically, my question is what is main disadvantage of evaluating each of them separately for given broadening parameters ($\gamma$ in Lorentzian, $\sigma$ in Gaussian) and then convolving the results numerically?
What would be the most prohibitive for such a procedure? The computing time of the numerical convolution? Precision? The integral boundaries can be clipped to some reasonable range. Most spectral lines are anyway computed only a few Angstroms away from the line center.

Given that both the Gaussian profile and the Lorentzian profile have analytic expressions for their Fourier transforms ($\exp(-q^2\sigma^2/2)$ and $\exp(-\gamma {|q|}^2)$, respectively), the most straightforward way to generate a Voigt profile is to sample the product of these two Fourier transforms in Fourier space and then perform a numerical inverse Fourier transform of that data to get the Voigt profile in real space. This way is the most efficient since only a single Fourier transform is required.

Typo in my previous comment: I meant to type $\exp(-\gamma|q|)$.

Thanks, John. Yes, this is the straightforward approach, but still it is not commonly used in the astrophysical spectroscopy. In the radiative transfer codes usually one needs to repeat this evaluation for every point in the model times the number of spectral lines that are considered (which can be a few, but in some cases the number is enormous $\approx 10^7$ or more). So even fast FT is not fast enough.

Then I'm a little confused about what you're asking. Are we talking about calculating Voigt profiles for simulated spectral lines in some kind of spectroscopic model? Does each spectral line have distinct values for $\sigma$ and $\gamma$, and that's why the profile needs to be calculated separately for each line instead of just once?

Yes, indeed. $\gamma$ and $\sigma$ are different for every spectral line and at every location in the atmosphere. Computing detailed spectra in that case means evaluating $~10^{15} line profiles. Sorry for not being clear enough.
